# Calculating the Manhattan distance in the eight puzzle

Tags: python

I am working on a program to solve the Eight Puzzle in Python using informed search w/ heuristics. The heuristic we are supposed to use is the Manhattan distance. So for a board like:

```
 State            Goal        Different Goal
7  2  4         1  2  3           1  2  3
5     6         8     4           4  5  6
8  3  1         7  6  5           7  8
```

The Manhattan distance would be `4 + 0 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 0 + 2 + 1 = 14`

Visually, it is easy to count how many spaces away a certain number is, but in Python I am representing a board as a list, so the board above would be `[7, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 8, 3, 1]` and the goal state would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`. I've been messing around trying to get this to work using mod but can't seem to get it working properly. My teacher said using mod would be helpful in figuring out how to do this. Some examples I looked at used a 2d array for the `abs(x_val - x_goal) + abs(y_val - y_goal)` which makes sense, but since I am using a list I am not sure how to implement this. The code I got so far is:

```
distance = 0
xVal = 0
yVal = 0
for i in range(len(self.layoutList)):
    pos = self.layoutList.index(i)
    if pos i == 0 or pos i == 1 or pos i == 2:
        xVal = pos
        yVal = 0
    if pos i == 3 or pos i == 4 or pos i == 5:
        xVal = pos - 3
        yVal = 1
    if pos i == 6 or pos i == 7 or pos i == 8:
        xVal = pos - 6
        yVal = 2
```

This would generate an x, y value for each tile. So the state above represented as `[7, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 8, 3, 1]` would generate `(0, 0)` for 7, `(2, 0)` for 4, etc. I would implement this the same way for the goalstate to get the x,y coordinates for that. Then I would take the absolute value of the x-val - x_goal and whatnot. But is there a better/more efficient way of doing this from the list directly instead of using 2 for loops to iterate both lists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Summing over each number's Manhatten distance:

```
>>> board = [7, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 8, 3, 1]
>>> sum(abs((val-1)%3 - i%3) + abs((val-1)//3 - i//3)
        for i, val in enumerate(board) if val)
14
```

For example, the 7 belongs at (zero-based) coordinate (0, 2) = (`(7-1)%3`, `(7-1)//3`) but is at coordinate (0, 0), so add `abs(0 - 0) + abs(2 - 0)` for it.

For non-standard goals:

```
>>> goal = [1, 2, 3, 8, 0, 4, 7, 6, 5]
>>> sum(abs(b%3 - g%3) + abs(b//3 - g//3)
        for b, g in ((board.index(i), goal.index(i)) for i in range(1, 9)))
16
```

Comment: I see that you use the list `board`, but does this check the values of the goal state? I don't see the goal state mentioned here.

Comment: @GenericUser01 I don't see non-standard goal states mentioned in your question. Do you really have to support that?

Comment: We do need to support that since there are different goal states in different versions of the 8-puzzle. Some 8-puzzles have a goal state of `[1, 2, 3, 8, 0, 4, 7, 6, 5]` which is the numbers 1-8 on the edges with the space in the middle.

Comment: The Manhattan is defined as `abs(x_value - x_goal) + abs(y-value - y_goal)` where x_goal and y_goal are x and y value of the given element in the goal state.

Comment: @GenericUser01 "updated" as in "changed the question", which is generally not cool. But ok, I already added a solution for non-standard goals. Better include the correct output for your added example, though.

Comment: I apologize if "changing the question" resulted in a different solution. I thought that there would be a general algorithm that would work for any and all goal states so I didn't think it mattered what goal state it was.

Comment: @GenericUser01 Better **always** use "odd" examples showing the full problem. I've also for example seen many questions about lists and the examples were sorted and had no duplicates while in reality the people also wanted to handle unsorted lists with duplicates. Anyway, I like my generalized solution better than my standard one, so I'm glad I wrote that as well :-). And I don't think paisanco's answer attempts to solve the problem at all, so standard vs non-standard goal probably doesn't matter for it...

Comment: @GrishaLevit Thanks for cueing me into that detail on the numbering. When I've seen algorithms for manhattan distance it's been in the context of solutions to the n-puzzle with 0 in the upper left corner (for which you wouldn't have the -1).